# Acrylic blur on sprite

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++-winrt, windows-composition-api

I tweaked the code in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-visual-layer-with-win32) to have a blur on the sprites generated by it. By using Effect brushes as per this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositioneffectbrush?view=winrt-22621) and also guidance from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115485/win2d-effects-in-ui-composition-c). However, the sprite remains unaffected whatsoever and doesn't blur at all.
Here is the tweaked code for `AddElement`

```c
void CompositionHost::AddElement(float size, float x, float y)
{
    if (m_target.Root()) // if there is an actual visual root
    {

        auto visuals = m_target.Root().as<ContainerVisual>().Children();
        auto visual = m_compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        // CreateSpriteVisual creates an instance of a SpriteVisual which is basically a 2D box

        auto element = m_compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        uint8_t r = (double)(double)(rand() % 255);
        ;
        uint8_t g = (double)(double)(rand() % 255);
        ;
        uint8_t b = (double)(double)(rand() % 255);
        ;

        GaussianBlurEffect blurEffect{};
        winrt::hstring blurStr = winrt::hstring(L"Blur");
        blurEffect.Name(blurStr);
        blurEffect.BlurAmount(1.0f);
        blurEffect.BorderMode(EffectBorderMode::Hard);
        blurEffect.Optimization(EffectOptimization::Balanced);

        CompositionEffectSourceParameter sourceParameter = CompositionEffectSourceParameter(L"source");
        blurEffect.Source(sourceParameter);

        CompositionEffectFactory blurEffectFactory = m_compositor.CreateEffectFactory(blurEffect);
        CompositionEffectBrush blurBrush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();

        CompositionBackdropBrush backDropBrush = m_compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
        blurBrush.SetSourceParameter(L"source", backDropBrush); // bind backdrop brush to effect brush

        element.Brush(blurBrush); // paints that 2D box
        element.Size({ size, size });
        element.Offset({
            x,
            y,
            0.0f,
            });

        auto animation = m_compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
        auto bottom = (float)600 - element.Size().y;                  // setting the y-coord of the 1st keyframe where animation should start atz
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(1, { element.Offset().x, bottom, 0 }); // telling where the first keyfram should start at

        using timeSpan = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 1>>; // <> is a template, instead of having many functions for different data types
        // you specify the data types inside <>

        std::chrono::seconds duration(2); // construct new duration, similar to = sign
        std::chrono::seconds delay(3);

        animation.Duration(timeSpan(duration));
        animation.DelayTime(timeSpan(delay)); // delay before animation starts
        element.StartAnimation(L"Offset", animation);

        visuals.InsertAtTop(element); // insert the color on top, top refers to the topmost of the app I think

        visuals.InsertAtTop(visual); // insert the 2D box on top
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a desktop app or a UWP app?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT it's a desktop app